# Problem including folders in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-import, importerror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViYBj.png)[**enter image description here**][2]

**I'm new to visual studio code, and I have the following folder structure:

`PythonProject\folder-a\a.py`

`PythonProject\folder-b\b.py`

am trying to import the python file `b.py` to the file `a.py`.

The way I have imported the file (from folder-b.b `import *`) works in my pycharm IDE, but when I try to run the file in visual studio code i get the error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder-b'`

I can run programs as expected, import files within the same folder, but not from a different folder. Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in your **ContinuousPF.py** file:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(".")
from Loadflow.PowerEq import *
```

This happens when you try to import beyond top level package.

If you are still facing the problem try debugging with this:

```py
import os
print (os.getcwd())
```

Comment: Awsome! The first approach worked just fine, thank you!